# converting date format in an access table with sql update

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a problem converting dates while updating an SQL table in VB under access: here is my code:

```
'Excel format date conversion
strSQL = "UPDATE tblBlotterINTLControl " & _
            "SET tblBlotterINTLControl.TradeDate = CVDate(TradeDate), " & _
                "tblBlotterINTLControl.SettleDate = CVDate(SettleDate);"
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

I obtain an error for each row: "type conversion error"
I have my tables in the right format though, please help thanks

EDIT:
I have to say that a SELECT request works but an UPDATE request doesn't! why? how?

Comment: what datatype are the columns?

Comment: Datatype inside the table are in Excel date format, it can be 19 aug. or 8/19 or even 40710

Comment: Not the data IN the columns, but the columns DATATYPE. Like VARCHAR, LONG etc. Also, it would be great if you could post the specific data the query fails for.

Comment: I tried several datatype for theses 2 columns inside my talbe but neither string nor date works

Comment: What are the values for TradeDate and SettleDate?  Are they valid dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the data types of the TradeDate and SettleDate fields in the Access table tblBlotterINTLControl?

```
SELECT TypeName(TradeDate) AS TypeOfTradeDate, TypeName(SettleDate) AS TypeOfSettleDate
FROM tblBlotterINTLControl;
```

Please paste that query into SQL View of a new query in Access, run it and show us what you get back.

The reason I asked is because the SET statements in your UPDATE query puzzle me.

```
SET tblBlotterINTLControl.TradeDate = CVDate(TradeDate)
```

If the TradeDate field is Date/Time datatype, using the CVDate() function on it doesn't accomplish anything.

If the TradeDate field is text datatype, CVDate() will give you a variant date, but you can't store that Date/Time value back to your text field.

Maybe you would be better off using the Format() function.  Here is a sample I copied from the Immediate Window:

```
? Format("2011/01/01", "d mmm yyyy")
1 Jan 2011
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `CDate` instead of `CVDate`.

CVDate actually returns a Variant of type vbDate and is only around for backwards comparability. Maybe that's what causing the problems.